# Adjustable Capacitance Circuit

Tags: capacitor

I'm designing a circuit where I want to be able to adjust the effective capacitance between two points, A and B.

To do this, I've essentially put a dip switch into a circuit with a bunch of caps on the other side. My goal is that I'd like to be able to turn off and on various combinations of capacitors to be able to achieve different levels of total capacitance.

In the diagram below, ignore the part numbers and just assume the caps can take on any value.

Am I doing this sort of thing right? Is there a better way? Also, is it OK to have the return path on the bottom and still expect the capacitor values will add up as a linear combination? Typically when I see this sort of thing the last capacitor in the parallel group is the return path.

[image]

As some context, A and B will get connected to pin 8 and the junction on pin 1 in this circuit.

[image]

Comment: the capacitors and switches are not necessary ... if you remove all the switches and all the caps, then you will still have the same short circuit

Comment: A and B go somewhere -- I've added a picture for context @jsotola

Comment: Look at the bottom of your circuit, what I think you call 'return path' is a short circuit which will make the circuit useless and just that: a short circuit.

Comment: @jsinglet I recognize that schematic symbol.  It's an AT42QT1010 / AT42QT1011, and I've been through previous nightmare projects trying to tune the Cs for this QTouch series.  Is your goal to use this switch setup in a prototype to help you easily tweak a final value for production?  Or are the switches meant for the end-user to play with and configure themselves?

Comment: If cost is no object, you can get sockets which take SMD parts, in case that's any help.

Comment: you nailed it @SteKulov -- that's exactly my plan. I'm ordering some boards but until I have the actual pads in the actual enclosure I only have a guess of what I need the final values to be. The typical cap values are between 2nF and 50nF, so my plan was to create an adjustable array to determine the final values WITH the printed sensors on board.

Comment: @HarryH -- thank you -- I see that now, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @SteKulov - After reading your comment about the "nightmare" -- I was also considering the TI CapTIvate chips which don't require this hardware tuning. Care to share thoughts / lessons learned?

Comment: @jsinglet Sure, I'll split it up into two comments. Our customer didn't want to pay for software, so they forced us to use the hardware strapped version.  We used the 4-button one, the AT42QT1040. These things are very sensitive to metal in the vicinity. This was used for the seat controls (fan/lights) for an unamed "Jet" [made by a company that also makes something called a "Civic" and an "Accord"], so the performance on the factory floor was totally different than after it was installed on the plane with all the extra metal everywhere.

Comment: @jsinglet The Atmel FAE came to help us out and even showed us some kind of strange debug mode to analyze internal registers. After a bunch of time wasted, he started to get pissed at us and told us these hardware strapped QTouch things are really only meant for cheap crappy plastic toys and not private jets with metal everywhere.  Anyway, if you can use one of the I2C versions, AT42QT1050 or AT42QT1070, you'll be better off.  You can tweak these via software instead of changing cap values.  Also a good idea to have the enclosure and try to make the proto PCB as close to final as possible.

Comment: @SteKulov -- that's some great information, thanks for sharing! My concern was exactly what you highlighted and that's a great story. I've also selected the CAP1203 and CAP1293, which both do I2C. Since I'm already using TI MCUs for other parts of the system I was looking hard at their MSP430 touch line. All of which do software calibration. You've given me something to think about for sure.

Comment: @jsinglet No problem, brother.  Not trying to scare you.  For what it's worth, single button might be much better than 4 buttons which all have nearby copper interfering with each other.  Regardless, for what it's worth in regards to the initial question, I think the initial approach is totally fine especially if you're in the nF range.  Once you're down into the pF, then the DIP switches' extra metal and parasitic capacitance might start causing headaches.  To help others in the future with a similar question, please accept one of the answers before moving on to a different approach.

Comment: May I ask what are the planned values of your capacitors?

Comment: Certainly @HarryH -- I panned to use: 1.2nF, 2.2nF, 6.8nF, 10nF, 15nF, 22nF, 33nF, 47nF. The stated normal range of this part of this component is 2nF - 50nF. It's probably possible of course to do it with less caps and combine them to cover a larger range of value -- I suppose I'm assuming it would be a better approximation to have a single cap acting rather than multiple, even if the values add. The smaller values allow me to add a little to the lager values if it feels close, but not quite there.

Comment: Ok, I was going to suggest a binary sequence like 1, 2, 4, 8, ... so that you can produce any value with a step size of the smallest one, but apparently you have given it a thought already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup may be okay for trials, to arrive at the optimum value of capacitance, after the short circuit is removed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the intention is for trials.

Comment: Anytime! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The way it is drawn, as mentioned by @jaysotola, you have a short between A and B.  That last node should be removed, regardless of context.

If you are looking at n- or p- Farad values, they do make variable capacitors.  Some can be large, like some of the old school radio tuners,  or small, like a little trim-pot, but it's a capacitor instead.  There may be higher values available, but I'm not sure on that.

Practicality would probably be pathetic, but perhaps you could make your own.  Take two straps of foil, make them really smooth, put some sort of dielectric between them (not sure on the specifics here. Experiment time!), and Bam!  Capcitor.  Press them together with something flat and insulating, and you change the capacitance.  A search on YouTube for "DIY capacitor" will lead you to some more info on caps like this.

Comment: The values are in the n/p Farad range. I think my concern with those is at the end of my testing I wanted to identify specific part/s I could throw on the board. With the variable capacitor I was concerned I'd need another round of testing just for this one aspect, perhaps due to the fact different types of capacitors would be being used in the final design.

Answer (score 0):

If you want manual control then yes, just remove the short circuit between A and B which others have pointed out.

If you have a limited set of combinations you could make a multiple rotary wafer switch from a standard kit, but that would be more expensive - and harder to troubleshoot - than your row of dip switches.

Depending on the range and precision of values you are after, you might alternatively consider a variable capacitor and mark out the dial positions for different nominal values. You could even use that for finer adjustments, with one or two big caps for gross range selection.

There are more sophisticated techniques with a smaller footprint, such as amplifying the apparent capacitance with an op-amp and selecting its gain via a variable resistor setup, but I am guessing you do not want to go there?

Comment: That's a fascinating idea -- I'll read up on that technique! Thanks for suggesting it.